# Get input (filenames) from tensorflow dataset iterators

Tags: python, tensorflow, iterator, tensorflow-datasets

I am using tensorflow datasets to train a model. A list of filenames is taken by the dataset to read them during the session, and I would like to get the filename together with the image. 
In more detail, I have something like this:

```
filenames = tf.constant(["/var/data/image1.jpg", "/var/data/image2.jpg", ...])
labels = tf.constant([0, 37, ...])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset.shuffle()

def _parse_function(filename, label):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [28, 28])
  return image_resized, label

dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
X, Y = iterator.get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
while True:
  sess.run(X) #Here I want the element from filenames being used for X
```

I thought that this information could be included in the `iterator`, but I could not find it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, here `X` will have the current file name.

Comment: @jdehesa Sorry, I wanted to simplify the code so much that I left it incomplete. I edited it now, X is an image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to keep the filename along with the image data in the dataset:

```
filenames = tf.constant(["/var/data/image1.jpg", "/var/data/image2.jpg", ...])
labels = tf.constant([0, 37, ...])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames, labels))
dataset.shuffle()

def _parse_function(filename, label):
  image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
  image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string)
  image_resized = tf.image.resize_images(image_decoded, [28, 28])
  return filename, image_resized, label

dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
F, X, Y = iterator.get_next()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(iterator.initializer)
while True:
  sess.run(F, X)
```